# Linking Errors after Visual Studio 2012 to 2017 migration

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am migrating my project from Visual Studio 2012 to 2017. I have selected Windows sdk V 10.0.17763.0 and and platform toolset as Visual Studio 2017 (v141) for all the projects in a solution. and target WINVER 0x0601 . Apart from this i have not made any changes .When I compile all the projects compile but i get error during Linking .There around 400 errors .I am linking the source files of static library files which belongs to other project (Added in additional include directories).Looks like most of the errors are coming from files that belongs to that project. I have even changed the toolset/sdk settings for that project. I am pretty much stuck .Unable to find out the root cause for this error .

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl RemoveRefForStatic(class GlobalSignalSourceInfo *)" (??$RemoveRefForStatic@VGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@@YAXPAVGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ATL::CAtlComModule::CAtlComModule(void)" (??0CAtlComModule@ATL@@QAE@XZ)   CSMediaPlayer   D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface    D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface\CSMediaEngine.lib(StdAfx.obj)

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void **cdecl AddRefForStatic(class GlobalSignalSourceInfo *)" (??$AddRefForStatic@VGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@@YAXPAVGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@Z) referenced in function "long __stdcall ATL::AtlWinModuleTerm(struct ATL::_ATL_WIN_MODULE70 *,struct HINSTANCE** *)" (?AtlWinModuleTerm@ATL@@YGJPAU_ATL_WIN_MODULE70@1@PAUHINSTANCE__@@@Z)  CSMediaPlayer   D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface    D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface\CSMediaEngine.lib(StdAfx.obj)  1

Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl RemoveRefForStatic(class GlobalSignalSourceInfo *)" (??$RemoveRefForStatic@VGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@@YAXPAVGlobalSignalSourceInfo@@@Z)  CSMediaPlayer   D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface    D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface\CSLib.lib(criticalsection.obj) 1

Error   LNK1120 18 unresolved externals CSMediaPlayer   D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface\Debug  D:\CoolSign\trunk\Development\common\2008\CSMediaPlayer_CEF\COMInterface\Debug\CSMediaPlayer.dll    1

Comment: set option `/VERBOSE:LIB` and look which libs actually included. your symbols say exist in `mfcs140u.lib` etc

Comment: you use `CSMediaEngine.lib` which linked with **old** atl/mfc libs. and try use new libs too. so you need or rebuild `CSMediaEngine.lib` with new libs too, or use old libs anywhere